# Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$. Let $A\subseteq V$. We say that $A$ is linearly independent if...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$. Let $A\subseteq V$. We say that $A$ is linearly independent if every finite subset of $A$ is linearly independent.

**Can you give an example?**

Comment: $A = \{(1,0)\}$, $V =\Bbb R^2$

Comment: Let $V$ be the set of fuctions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Then $A=\left\{ e^{\lambda t}:\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$ is lin. indep, right?

Comment: You also have the set of sequences $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$ (*or [$\ell^\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) or however else you wish to refer to it as*) and the linearly independent set $\{(1,0,0,0,\dots),(0,1,0,0,\dots),(0,0,1,0,\dots),\dots\}$.  there are of course infinitely many other correct examples.

Comment: @Kahler Yes.  That's also an example.

Comment: @Kahler are you specifically interested in examples of infinite sets $A$?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibly deceptive example: consider the space $\ell^2$ of square-summable infinite sequences.  Let 
$$
e_1 = (1,0,0,0,\dots)\\
e_2 = (0,1,0,0,\dots)\\
e_3 = (0,0,1,0,\dots)
$$
and so forth.  Let $x$ be the sequence
$$
x = (1,1/2,1/4,1/8,\dots)
$$
You may be surprised to find that, by our definition, the set $A = \{x\} \cup \{e_i : i \in \Bbb N\}$ is actually *linearly independent*, even though we might say that
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^{i-1}} e_i
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, the standard basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is linearly independent since its every finite subset, including itself, is linearly independent.
If $V$ is infinite dimensional, such as $F[x]$, the vector space of polynomials with coefficients in a field $F$, has a basis $\{x^i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$, and it is linearly independent since its arbitrary finite subset, ${x^{i_1}, ...,x^{i_k}}$ is linearly independent, by definition of linear independence.